# Органическая форма с CSS для эффекта наложения на изображения

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

У меня есть задача по изображению органической формы.

Я хочу, чтобы фоновый цвет при наведении был, как изображение определенной органической формы. 
Но, я не получаю эффект наведения на изображении с цветом фона.

Я много пробовал, но он не получается, где я делаю неправильно?
 Может  кто-нибудь указать  правильное направление, чтобы решить мою проблему? Заранее спасибо...

```css
.at-organic-shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.at-organic-shape figure img:hover {
  background-color: #6495ED;
  border-radius: 35% 80% 65% 70%/50% 65% 70% 85%;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="at-organic-shape">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nHDcuq/1-F19-F06-C-0-F3-E-4055-B0-E5-1-D73728-A7730.png" class="img1"/>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53445622/7394871

Comment: а Вы перелинковку не делаете? Смотрю, там ответов не густо. А так, может к нам бы заглядывали с аглицкого SO, русский язык бы подучили))

Comment: @UModeL у нас по программе ассоциаций только Enso -> Ru  программа работает в полуавтоматическом режиме. После комментария `ассоциация ` со временем появляется плашка на Enso - ""Этот вопрос есть и на русском"  Обратной процедуры RU -> Enso пока нет. Но вы всегда можете перевести свой ответ и разместить его на  ENso

Comment: плашка, что вопрос есть на русском - это хорошо. Но, полезнее была бы плашка - на enSO, что есть ОТВЕТ на русском SO))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я всё правильно понял - есть картинка с прозрачностью (.png) и нужно её "замонохромить" определённым цветом? Если да, то как вариант:

```css
img {
  transition: -webkit-filter 0.4s ease-out, filter 0.4s ease-out;
}
img:hover {
  --hue: 140deg;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) sepia(1) hue-rotate(var(--hue)) saturate(2);
  filter: grayscale(1) sepia(1) hue-rotate(var(--hue)) saturate(2);
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 336px;
  background: hsl(180, 80%, 65%);
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  border: 0px dotted #090;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="at-organic-shape">
  <figure>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="360" oninput="this.style.background = 'hsl(' + this.value + ', 80%, 65%)';document.querySelector('img').style.setProperty('--hue', this.value - 40 + 'deg');document.querySelector('span').innerText = 'hue-rotate(' + (this.value - 40) + 'deg)';"><span>hue-rotate(140deg)</span>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nHDcuq/1-F19-F06-C-0-F3-E-4055-B0-E5-1-D73728-A7730.png" class="img1" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

*Вся "магия" в строчке с фильтрами, остальной код для украшательства.*

Comment: @Alexandr_TT там нужно не значение `hsl`, а значение для `hue-rotate()`, ибо после применения `sepia()` значения смещаются. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 5):

> [Перевод ответа @Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446778/7394871) на вопрос EnSO: [Organic Shape with
>   CSS For Image Hover Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53445622/7394871)

Вы можете попытаться использовать псевдоэлемент и режим `mix-blend-mode`, чтобы скрыть переполнение цвета:

```css
.at-organic-shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.at-organic-shape figure {
  position:relative;
  background:#fff;
}
.at-organic-shape figure:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.at-organic-shape figure:hover::after {
  background:#6495ED;
}
```

```html
<div class="at-organic-shape">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nHDcuq/1-F19-F06-C-0-F3-E-4055-B0-E5-1-D73728-A7730.png" class="img1"/>
  </figure>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446778/7394871): @Temani Afif